# Run Ansible task conditionally and fail if condition is not met

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I am very new to Ansible and having an issue.
I want to run the module only if a condition is met but if the condition is failed, it should fail the task and report to user.
Currently what I have done, it will only skip it rather than failing it.

Below is my code, I have the when condition to check and only run if  result.stdout == 'valid' but I want to fail the task if its 'invalid'.Currently it just skips it if condition not met.

```
---
- name: Check Value
  become: yes
  shell: /usr/bin/python3 check.py
  args:
    chdir: "mydir/scripts/"
  register: result
  tags: data_merge

- name: Merge Data
  become: yes
  when: result.stdout == 'valid'
  local_action:
    module: some_module
    provider: "{{some_provider}}"
    role_path: "{{role_path}}"
  run_once: true
  tags: data_merge
```

Answer (score 6):

You have three options:

Use `failed_when` to make the playbook fail checking a condition. I'd suggest to add a exit code to the python script (e.g.: `exit(255 if error else 0)`), it's cleaner than parsing the `stdout`:

```yaml
- name: Check Value
  shell: /usr/bin/python3 check.py
  args:
    chdir: "mydir/scripts/"
  register: result
  failed_when: result.rc != 0
  tags: data_merge
```

`fail` will kill the application printing an error message:

```yaml
- name: Fail on not valid
  fail:
    msg: failed
  when: result.stdout != 'valid'
```

`meta: end_play` will silently stop the application (but this may not be useful if you want a feedback output)

```yaml
- name: Stop on not valid
  meta: end_play
  when: result.stdout != 'valid'
```

Either way you don't need the `when: result.stdout == 'valid'` in the *Merge Data* anymore.

Answer (score 3):

You should fail yourself explicitly in this scenario.

```
- name: Fail when value is not valid
  fail:
    msg: "A custom message to tell the user what went wrong"
  when: result.stdout != 'valid'
```

You can also simply check the result directly in the play which runs your check script.

```
- name: Check Value
  become: yes
  shell: /usr/bin/python3 check.py
  args:
    chdir: "mydir/scripts/"
  register: result
  tags: data_merge
  failed_when: "'invalid' in result.stdout"
```

You should consider using exit codes in your application to indicate success or failure, as most programs already do. This makes for a much more reliable check than checking for text on stdout. Use [`sys.exit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit) in Python to do this. In that case, checking for failure is simply when `result.rc != 0`.

(And of course you should use `command` instead of `shell` whenever possible.)